# Make more efficient code for some jquery array split

Tags: jquery

I am having fun with jquery, and wonder if you can help make my code more efficient. Below is the only working code I can do so far. Any other trial is not happy:

**HTML**

```
<div class="someparent">...<p><input type="text"  value="0 0 12 12" class="radius"></p></div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
    $('input.radius').each(function() {
            var preview = $(this).parents('.someparent');   

            $(this).keyup(function() {
                var rad = $(this).val();

                c = rad.split(' ');
                tl = c[0] ? c[0] + 'px' : '';
                tr = c[1] ? c[1] + 'px' : '';
                bl = c[2] ? c[2] + 'px' : '';
                br = c[3] ? c[3] + 'px' : '';

                var radius = tl + ' ' +  tr + ' ' + bl + ' ' + br;              
                $(preview).css('border-radius', radius);
            });
            if ($(this).val()) {
                var rad = $(this).val();

                c = rad.split(' ');
                tl = c[0] ? c[0] + 'px' : '';
                tr = c[1] ? c[1] + 'px' : '';
                bl = c[2] ? c[2] + 'px' : '';
                br = c[3] ? c[3] + 'px' : '';

                var radius = tl + ' ' +  tr + ' ' + bl + ' ' + br;                  
                preview.css('border-radius', radius);
            }
     });
```

Basically the code wants to update dynamically the properties based on any input, while keeping its current state whenever available as default.
Thanks for any help

Comment: if values always initial without pixel, simply use `c = rad.split(' ').join('px ');`

Comment: @Omid: why not post that as an answer instead of a comment, if that's a solution?

Comment: yes, its always pixel for simplicity. Thanks. But I wonder how to merge both chunks of similar codes into one, if possible. If not, then that's the way it is, is it? Hope not :)

Comment: @swan: I post a new answer that may optimize your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if values always initial without pixel, simply use:

```
$('input.radius').each(function() {
    var preview = $(this).parents('.someparent'); 

    $(this).keyup(function() {
        var rad = $(this).val();
        c = rad.split(' ').join('px ');
        $(preview).css('border-radius', c);
    }).keyup(); // trigger keyup manually to initial
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot better. Any way to combine both similar chunks?

Comment: Wow, beautiful. Thanks. I just remembered that I have ever used that trigger keyup, only the context is select box with change();. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

For text change, I prefer use `change` event.

```
$('input.radius').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var rad = $this.val();
    if (rad) {
        $this.parents('.someparent').css('border-radius', rad.split(' ').join('px '));
    }
});
```

Comment: This sounds more user friendly, no need to add a space to update the preview, right? But strangely I keep getting "syntax error". Thanks

Comment: @swan I miss the `;` and `function`, fixed.

Comment: Ok, you missed function() declation, but no more user friendly I am afraid. I meant no immediate effect on changing text, I still have to add a space. Any idea to live update?

Comment: The only problem is that `change` event will not fire till you blur textbox.

Comment: @swan If you want immediately update, change `change` to `keyup`

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying, both codes are great already. Thanks a lot